# Spring Data REST PUT Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data

I recently implemented Spring Data REST (http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest) in order to expose CRUD functionality through a REST interface automatically.

GET and POST both work as expected, however I'm getting a 405 Method Not Allowed when using the PUT Verb.

According to the documentation

```
Verb    Method
GET     CrudRepository<ID,T>.findOne(ID id)
POST    CrudRepository<ID,T>.save(T entity)
PUT     CrudRepository<ID,T>.save(T entity)
DELETE  CrudRepository<ID,T>.delete(ID id)
```

By default, all of these methods are exported to clients. I've read through the documentation here (http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/rest/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/) but can't seem to find a reason for this behaviour.

Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong? I have provided a RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration class which defines resource mapping for all my Entity classes.

Comment: what url are you using to make the `PUT` request?

Comment: @soulcheck Same URL that works for POST, just changing the verb to PUT. ie "http://localhost:8080/<applicationname>/<entityName> and then passing in a JSON body for the content of the entity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are trying to use the same url for `POST` and `PUT` requests, but `PUT` usually requires the id of the object that has to be updated.

Spring does have mapping for `localhost:8080/<applicationname>/<entityName>`, but only for `POST` request and hence the error.

Try using `PUT` with:

```
http://localhost:8080/<applicationname>/<entityName>/<objectId>
```

Comment: Ha - brilliant, stuck a random number at the end for the <objectId> and it worked first time. Now, we have IDs being auto-generated by Hibernate (well the underlying DB) so I'll have to see how this works, but thanks for your help

Comment: @AndyEsser did you get around hibernate auto generating the ids on put?